# IPA, Doulos SIL, footnotesize and beamerposter

Tags: footnotes, beamerposter, tipa

beamerposter allows to generate PDF files, that can be used on a device like the iPad.
Unfortunately when using footnotes in a frame, beamerposter inserts an empty page, since the footnotesize font is too large.
Usually \renewcommand*{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
solved the problem.

However when use IPA and Doulous SIL this solution no longer works, any ideas what to do?
Thanks

The example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a4,scale=4]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}
\setsansfont{Doulos SIL}
\renewcommand*{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{IPA, Doulos SIL, footnotesize and beamerposter}
  \begin{center}

/ˈuːv ə/
Consider\footnote{in the literal sense}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well beamerposter redefines \normalfont: `\renewcommand*{\normalfont}{\normalsize}`. And that basically means that the size is reset in inexpected places. I wouldn't use that package.

Comment: Hm, what puzzles me is that for the font \setmainfont{Doulos SIL} this leads to problems while 'standard' fonts seem ok.
right now I solve my problem by using

`\documentclass[handaout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\geometry{papersize={11in,8.5in}}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper=true,noautoscale,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{beamer.pdf}
\end{document}
`

Comment: it doesn't work with standard fonts for me.